# Optional Group Expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Today I was working with regular expressions at work and during some experimentation I noticed that a regex such as `(\w|)` compiled. This seems to be an optional group but looking online didn't yield any results.

Is there any practical use of having a group that matches something, but otherwise can match anything? What's the difference between that and `(\w|.*)`? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing matches any zero-length substring of the string which is _between_ any two characters or the positions before the first and behind the last character. As a captured group like `/()/g` you’d get empty strings as results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(\w|)` is a verbose way of writing `\w?`, which checks for `\w` first, then empty string.

<sup>I remove the capturing group, since it seems that `()` is used for *grouping* property only. If you actually need the capturing group, then `(\w?)`.</sup>

On the same vein, `(|\w)` is a verbose way of writing `\w??`, which tries for empty string first, before trying for `\w`.

---

`(\w|.*)` is a different regex altogether. It tries to match (in that order) one word character `\w`, **or** 0 or more of any character (except line terminators) `.*`.

I can't imagine how this regex fragment would be useful, though.