# Perl optional group in arbitrary place

Tags: regex, perl, option-type

I need to capture sereral groups and some of them are optional. I've read about optional in https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html but `?` does not work for me. Example file:

```
Code>1<Code
foo
Prod>2<Prod
foo
Type>3<Type
```

`perl -0777ne 'print qq($1;$2;$3) if /Code>(.*?)<Code.*?Prod>(.*?)<Prod.*?Type>(.*?)<Type/s' < tst.txt` gives `1;2;3` as expected.

Now I want to add optionality to second group like `perl -0777ne 'print qq($1;$2;$3) if /Code>(.*?)<Code.*?(Prod>(.*?)<Prod)?.*?Type>(.*?)<Type/s' < tst.txt`, but it stops to print second group, giving `1;;` (due to nested 3rd empty same as the 2nd, $4 prints `3`).

Per [Optional Group Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472600/optional-group-expression) I've tried `perl -0777ne 'print qq($1;$2;$3;$4) if /Code>(.*?)<Code.*?(Prod>(.*?)<Prod|.*?).*?Type>(.*?)<Type/s' < tst.txt` but again have `1;;;3`.

Is it possible to extract optionally in any place as I can have other stuff between groups and how?

EDIT:
removing one `?` `perl -0777ne 'print qq($1;$2;$3;$4) if /Code>(.*?)<Code.*?(Prod>(.*?)<Prod|.*).*?Type>(.*?)<Type/s' < tst.txt` gives
`1;
foo
Prod>2<Prod
foo
;;3`
so captures everything between 1st and 3rd (looks like 2nd option is extracted, not one before `|`), not only 2nd.

EDIT:
implemented `?:` suggestion, now `perl -0777ne 'print qq($1;$2;$3;$4) if /Code>(.*?)<Code.*?(?:Prod>(.*?)<Prod|.*).*?Type>(.*?)<Type/s' < tst.txt` gives `1;;3;`

Comment: Why are you printing out `$4` if you're only capturing 3 groups?

Comment: And why the `|.*` in the optional non-capturing group?

Comment: @Tanktalus, $4 was left due to quick edit; `|.*` - actually the group does not have `?` after `)` so I think it's not optional, why do you write it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `(?:...)` - the `?:` prefix inside the capture group makes it into simply a group, not captured. I recommend using this every time there is a group that is not captured to make your intent clearer.  It says, "I'm grouping this, but not keeping it." It may even make the runtime faster, but that's not the main benefit.

Example:

```
perl -0777nE 'say qq[$1;$2;$3] if /Code\>(.*?)\<Code.*?(?:Prod\>(.*?)\<Prod.*?)?Type\>(.*?)\<Type/s' < t
```

This prints out `1;2;3`

However, I would also suggest looking at the `(?<name>...)` syntax where you can name your groups and use `%+` (e.g., `$+{name}`) to extract fields by name rather than position. In my experience, this makes both the regex and the code relying on it more readable.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, useful technique, I edited the question at the end. Still optionality is not solved. either from `|` it chooses second part or nested group from not kept one is not kept.

Comment: interestingly moving `.*?` inside optional group make it work, I yet have not grasped why.

Comment: Can I mix named and numbered? If yes, are named change number of subsequent numbered? I have numbered and want to add capturing optional one - I guess the only maybe possible way is to use named one. Thanx.

Comment: Using names doesn't change the numbering. That is, even if you use named captures, they are still available with the same number as if names weren't used. So if you add a named capture before some of your numbered captures, you'll end up with the numbers changing. Which is why I suggest using named for anything more than one or two captures in the first place.

Comment: if in match I have certain part 1, then arbitrary optional part 2 then fixed optional part 3 then again certain part 4 and I write 2 optional groups 2st with .*? lazy and 3nd fixed optional, will both be captured accordinly if present (that is would be something after 1st and then fixed 3rd text) or 2st capture will include 3nd fixed - is it determined or maybe implementation dependent? thanx

Comment: I tried to do thing in comment above and it captured both groups as I wanted. At least in my environment it works.